# My program was just working NOW this error?

Tags: java, recursion, compiler-errors, grid

My program literally was just working, about to turn it in, then compiled it again just to be safe, AND THIS ERROR?

I am desperate for some quick help because I comopletely do not know why my code decided abruptly to not work anymore:((((((((((((((

```
TrominoSolver.java:175: error: constructor tromino in class tromino cannot be applied to given types;
            tromino thisguy = new tromino(size, x, y);
                              ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Why am I getting this all of the sudden?

Here is my code

```
 import java.util.*;

public class TrominoSolver {
    //create a drawing panel of width=400px and height=400px

    private int[][] board;
    private int currentNum;

    // 0<=x<size, 0<=y<size
    // create an empty tromino object of dimension size x size.
    public void tromino(int size, int x, int y) {

        int actualsize = 1;
        while (actualsize < size) actualsize*=2;     //actualsize = actualsize * 2

        //Board is power of 2
        board = new int[actualsize][actualsize];
        currentNum = 1;

        // Initialize with empty squares.
        for (int i=0; i<actualsize; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<actualsize; j++) {
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        // Hole in board
        board[x][y] = -1;
    }

    // call for recursive method.
    public void tile() {
        tileRec(board.length, 0, 0);
    }

    private void tileRec(int size, int topx, int topy) {

        // fill in your one tromino...
        if (size == 2) {

            // Fill in the one tromino. The hole is identified by a
            // -num, don't fill in that one square.   
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
                for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
                    if (board[topx+i][topy+j] == 0)
                        board[topx+i][topy+j] = currentNum;

            // Advance to the next tromino.
            currentNum++;
        }

        // Recursive case...
        else {

            // Find coordinates of hole
            int yesx=topx, yesy=topy;

            for (int x=topx; x<topx+size; x++) 
                for (int y=topy; y<topy+size; y++)
                    if (board[x][y] != 0) {
                        yesx = x;
                        yesy = y;
                    }

            // Hole in upper left quadrant.     
            if (yesx < topx + size/2 && yesy < topy + size/2) {

                // Recursively tile upper left quadrant.
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);

                // Fill in middle tromino
                board[topx+size/2][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2] = currentNum;

                // Advance to the next tromino
                currentNum++;

                // make other recursive calls.
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);

            }

            // Hole in upper right quadrant
            else if (yesx < topx + size/2 && yesy >= topy + size/2) {

                // Recursively tile upper right quadrant.
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);

                // Fill in middle tromino
                board[topx+size/2][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;

                // Go to the next tromino
                currentNum++;

                // make other recursive calls.
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);

            }

            // Hole in bottom left quadrant
            else if (yesx >= topx + size/2 && yesy < topy + size/2) {

                // Recursively tile bottom left quadrant.
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);

                // Fill in middle tromino
                board[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;

                // Go to the next tromino
                currentNum++;

                // make other recursive calls.
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);
            }
            else {

                // Recursively tile bottom right quadrant.
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy+size/2);

                // Fill in middle tromino
                board[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;
                board[topx+size/2-1][topy+size/2-1] = currentNum;

                // Go to the next tromino
                currentNum++;

                // Now we can make our three other recursive calls.
                tileRec(size/2, topx+size/2, topy);
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy+size/2);
                tileRec(size/2, topx, topy);
            }

        } 

    } 

    // Print out latest object
    public void print() {

        for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        // user input...
        int size = stdin.nextInt();
        int x = stdin.nextInt();
        int y = stdin.nextInt();

        tromino thisguy = new tromino();
        thisguy.tile();

        // Print out the tromino board.
        thisguy.print();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change constructor name to TrominoSolver:

```
// 0<=x<size, 0<=y<size
// create an empty tromino object of dimension size x size.
public TrominoSolver(int size, int x, int y) {

    int actualsize = 1;
    ...
```

Update main to call correct constructor name:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    // user input...
    int size = stdin.nextInt();
    int x = stdin.nextInt();
    int y = stdin.nextInt();

    TrominoSolver thisguy = new TrominoSolver();
    thisguy.tile();

    // Print out the tromino board.
    thisguy.print();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they **use the name of the class** and **have no return type**, so instead of `public void tromino(int size, int x, int y) {` you should write `public TrominoSolver(int size, int x, int y) {`, then you can instantiate your class this way:  `TrominoSolver thisguy = new TrominoSolver(size, x, y);`

Answer (score 0):

Error is because

`tromino` is not your constructor, it is your method. Constructors do not have return type.

You can have no-arguement constructor (provided by default) or you can explicitly declare one or more constructors with arguements.

you can declare a contructor with arguements like this

```
public TrominoSolver(int size,int x,int y) {
  this.size=size;
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
}
```

provided `size , x and y` are members of your `TrominoSolver` class.

you can create an object using this constructor like this

```
TrominoSolver trominoSolver = new TrominoSolver(3,2,1);
```

call your method using `trominoSolver` reference.